# Multi Buy, differant prices 3 for $250

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, multiple-add-to-cart

I have a category full of shirts.

All shirts are different prices

What I am trying to do is if 3 shirts are selected the total cart price is $250

if 6 shirts are selected the cart price is $500

if 4 shirts are selected the first 3 are at $250 then the 4th shirt at full price

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? And if all shirts have different prices, which one is the 4th in your example? The least expensive? The most expensive? Any?

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I tried a shopping cart rule.. I can get it to written for 3 Shirts that are the same value.. Then deduct a fixed value of the shopping cart total

Comment: Sorry pressed enter my mistake.  The 4th shirt would be end highest priced one,  can we do this in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to realise this with shopping cart rules, not without custom code (which is IMHO too complex for a Stack Exchange answer, but maybe you are lucky and someone else has already done it)

A possible alternative is to create a bundle product "3 Shirts Offer" with a fixed price of $250 and three required dropdown options, "Shirt 1", "Shirt 2" and "Shirt 3". Add all shirts to each of the options. Now the customers can select which three shirts they want to buy for the $250  special offer. Not as user friendly as applying a discount automatically, but it works.